# Implement message prioritization in task queue

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, priority-queue, pika

How to implement priority queue using RabbitMQ using Python client(Pika/Kombu) or any other Task Queue ?

P.S. -> To implement Task Queue in Message Prioritization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a priority queue using `pika`.

```
channel.queue_declare('queue_name', {''x-max-priority': 10})
```

To send a message with priority

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange='exchange_name',
                      routing_key='routing_key',
                      body='Messsage',
                      properties=BasicProperties(priority=1))
```

You can set the `priority` value between 1 to 10, i.e. the maximum priority value that you have set. You can set a maximum priority value of 255, but RabbitMQ recommends the maximum value to be 10. [Reference](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html)

To consume the message, you define a callback function and call the `basic_consume` method

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):

    # Getting the message
    message = body.decode()

    ## Do the logic
    print('Received message {}'.format(message))

    # Sending acknowledgment back
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='queue_name')
```

The consumer for a priority queue is the same as the consumer for a normal queue. When you set a priority the messages get reordered based on the priority at the broker side. So you consume the messages normally without getting bothered about the messages.

**Note**: You cannot redeclare a queue as a priority queue. You gotta delete the old queue and declare the new one as a priority queue.

Comment: can you tell me how to consume data based on priority.

Comment: Added about consumer.

Comment: I received data  as FIFO not based on priority.

Comment: Can you add your sample of code where you are publishing the message with priority?

Comment: For sending (https://pastebin.com/raw/mv6s5gwr) and for receiving (https://pastebin.com/raw/EDVX3N4n)

Comment: The message with `priority` level 5 has more priority than the message with `priority` level 1. If you want your message `'Hello World! Mukul'` to have more priority then give it the max priority value that you have set.

Comment: Thanks! problem solved. Can you tell me how to set priority based on multiple conditions. For example: {"priority":1 "date_time": "2019-03-22 15:50:01.439861"}. How to set priority based datetime and multiple conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190493/discussion-between-bumblebee-and-mukul-mantosh).

Comment: Hello @Mukul Mantosh, If my solution has given you the desired output, please take some time and consider accepting it as the best answer.